# HTML's Table TD with default value

Tags: html

Is there any way to fill the empty `<td></td>`, if data does not exist in this?

```
<table><tr><td></td><td>1</td><td></td></tr></table>
```

Change it to:

```
<table><tr><td>Not Data</td><td>1</td><td>No Data</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not with HTML itself.

Usually you would do this by generating the HTML using a data in a programming language and a template, with template logic used to insert a default value if none came from the data.

Comment: Can we do it via JS on page load or something ?

Comment: @AnuragChoudhary — Yes. That would be using a programming language.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit hackish, because it changes only visual aspect. You can do that with CSS:

```css
table, td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 4px; border-collapse: collapse}
td:empty::before {content: "No Data"}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Real data</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Won't really work just with html.

it depends on how you build your HTML-DOM. If it is just a pure HTML-file (*.html ) you could check for value by adding some JavaScrit/JQuery.

But if you are trying to do this, make sure to give your table/tr or td to give element-ids.

```
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td id="1_1"></td>
    <td id="1_2">1</td>
    <td id="1_3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text">
/* For the amount of rows */
for(var outeri = 1; outeri <= 1; outeri++)
{
   /* For the amount of columns */
   for(var ineri = 1; ineri <= 3; ineri)
   {
       var innertd = String(outeri + '_' + ineri);

       if(document.getElementById(inntertd).innerHTML == '')
       {
          document.getElementById(inntertd).innerHTML = 'No Data';
       }
       else {continue;}
   }
}
</script>
```

This example is not very realistic and more likely not to be done unless your table is just static.

Answer (score 0):

you can add an empty space: &nbsp;

Comment: With the html entity "&nbsp;".

Comment: No, you can't. That would cause the cell to be rendered with no text in it even if if the CSS didn't have `empty-cells: show` (it's a nasty hack that we don't need to use now it is the 21st century). It won't cause *text* to be displayed in empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in many ways, here are 2 (c# and jquery)
Solutions:

c#:

Use razor as in the following:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   @{
      if(data)
      {
        <td>@data.name</td>
        <td>@data.date</td>     
      }
      else
      {
        <td colspan="2">NO DATA</td>
      } 
    }
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

Select the table and change the html depending on if there is any data

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var table = $("table-selector");
  var isData = $("data-selector").length;

  if(!isData){
    table.html("customize HTML right here, considering 'colspan' in case 
    there is a headers row as well")
  }
});
```